# setup:di:compile fails after update to magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2

Compilation was started.

```
Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 1 min 642.5 MiB
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:
                                                                                                                                        
 Warning: Undefined array key "instance" in /var/www/VENDOR/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/ArgumentsResolver.php on line 171
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the code in  /var/www/VENDOR/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/ArgumentsResolver.php on line 171

Do it like this:

> if(isset($this->getInstanceArgument($config['instance'])))
>
> {
> $argument = $this->getInstanceArgument($config['instance']);
>
> }

Then run setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

Do `bin/magento c:f` and then `bin/magento setup:di:compile` again