# Undefined array key "instance" in ArgumentsResolver.php on line 171 after upgrading to 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

After doing an update from 2.4.2 to 2.4.6 I am getting that error on compilation in compilation step 5 rfunning PHP 8.1. I searched a bit and found [setup:di:compile fails after update to magento 2.4.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356390/setupdicompile-fails-after-update-to-magento-2-4-4). I applied this solution, which gives me another error in compilation step 3:

**Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression**

So, any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the full error stack trace? I don't know what steps 3 and 5 you are referring to. Try to add verbose argument to your `bin/magento` command to get verbose output, eg:  `bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv`. And what is your PHP version?

Comment: I added -vvv and the result is: https://pastebin.com/uxVJfvb9
Added the other information in my post...thanks for helping!

Comment: The Pastebin link is not found, could you check it out?

Comment: Sure? Works for me, tried in different browsers...

Comment: I can access it now, somehow Patebin denies my IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to help you debug here.
Firstly, let's revert your change in line 171.
Then try to remove `generated` directory and cache directories too and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to make sure that anything related to this issue is cleared:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And recompile code with verbose argument:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
```

If the issue still persists, let's open `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/ArgumentsResolver.php`, and edit line 125 to dump the value of `$configuredArgument` variable which passes to
`getConfiguredInstanceArgument(array $config)` method - line 171

Replace
`$argument = $this->getConfiguredInstanceArgument($configuredArgument);`
with

```
var_dump($configuredArgument);
$argument = $this->getConfiguredInstanceArgument($configuredArgument);
```

Run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and check the result, if it's long lines result, paste it somewhere which allows sharing long lines of code like pastebin, and share it here.
If it works properly, it should output something similar to this:

```
Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 39 secs 390.0 MiBarray(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(40) "Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(37) "Magento\Backend\Block\MenuItemChecker"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(36) "Magento\Backend\Block\AnchorRenderer"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(46) "Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(63) "Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data\Collection\Proxy"
}
```

**Update: Output from OP's command:**

```
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(43) "Magento\Shipping\Model\Method\VirtualLogger"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(46) "Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(63) "Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data\Collection\Proxy"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(46) "Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(63) "Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data\Collection\Proxy"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(43) "Magento\Shipping\Model\Method\VirtualLogger"
}
array(1) {
  ["instance"]=>
  string(46) "Magento\Variable\Model\Config\StructureVirtual"
}
array(1) {
  ["general/imprint"]=>
  array(33) {
    ["general/imprint/shop_name"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ....
  }
}
```

Based on your output, the last item doesn't have `instance` node which caused the error.
The config indicates you are using FireGento MageSetup module and I guess you are still at an older version. They reported the error for Magento 2.4.3 and fixed it 2 years ago. https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup2/pull/200/files#diff-093a1e43a11122404c853506b7ca4f661e18dd4f6557ec3089cad8ceae34a606

So, to resolve your issue, edit `<FireGento_MageSetup module dir>/etc/di.xml` to replace

```
<type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables">
```

with

```
<type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Config\Structure\AvailableVariables">
```

or upgrade the FireGento MageSetup module to the latest version.

Read more about the FireGento MageSetup module at https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup2

Comment: Thanks! I added the suggested change to line 125 and this is the output: https://pastebin.com/XdkPzb5N. Thanks!

Comment: Could you confirm you have done   above steps before modify ArgumentsResolver.php file? I’m checking your output.

Comment: I've found the root cause of the issue and added the solution to my answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it, it was the MageSetup extension :-)!

Comment: @user4095519 Cool, glad to help!